# How to set `side: right` of `textPath` in Chrome?

Tags: d3.js, svg

`side` is not supported in Chrome.

And `rotate` on `textPath` dosen't work while `rotate` on `text` affects on `path` acctually what is not I really want.

```
textPath.attr("transform", "rotate(180)"); // not work

textPath.attr("side", "right"); // not work
```

Is there any other way to achieve the same effect？

Comment: How is your path being defined? Isn't there a way to define it the other way around? For instance instead of `d="M10,10L75,30"` you'd make  it `d="M75,30L10,10"`

Comment: Thx and if the direction of the `path` is from right to left，then I need to orient the `textPath` from left to right while the direction of the `path` is meaningful.

Comment: Not sure to get what you mean here... If you wish to keep the original direction of your path, then create a simili-clone, from which the `d` attribute is inversed and use this simili-clone as the target for your textPath. But my comment was really asking you to show us how you do define this path.

Comment: Just a path with arrow and textPath.And it is feasible  to reverse the path and hide it.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the next demo is taken from MDN. Is using `side` and it's not supported in Chrome.

The second part is the alternative solution where you are reversing the path as Kaiido suggested.

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:90vh;}

text {
  font: 25px Arial, Helvelica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 400" >
<!--MDN-->
  <text>
    <textPath href="#circle1" side="left">Side left</textPath>
  </text>
  <text>
    <textPath href="#circle2" side="right">Text right</textPath>
  </text>

  <circle id="circle1" cx="100" cy="100" r="70" fill="transparent" stroke="silver"/>
  <circle id="circle2" cx="320" cy="100" r="70" fill="transparent" stroke="silver"/>
<!--MDN-->
<!--Alternative solution-->  
  <path id="p1" d="M160,300A70,70 0 0 1 20 300" fill="none" stroke="red" />

  <text>
    <textPath href="#p1">path left</textPath>
  </text>
  
  <g transform ="translate(230,0)">"
  <path id="p2" d="M160,300A70,70 0 0 0 20 300" fill="none" stroke="red" />     
  <text>
    <textPath href="#p2">path right</textPath>
  </text>
  </g> 
<!--Alternative solution-->  
</svg>
```

Comment: As you take a look the p1 and p2 paths have _almost_ the same d value. The only difference is the sweep-flag. without the  `transform ="translate(230,0)"` the 2 paths would have overlapped. I'm translating the p2 to a different position on the same svg canvas. I could have used a different svg canvas for every shape.

Comment: is there a way that we can convert our circle path?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you. You want to convert the circle path to what? What circle path? Please can you ask all this in a question?

Comment: I see in your solution that <path id="p2" has d="M160,300A70,70 0 0 0 20 300" and p1 has d="M160,300A70,70 0 0 1 20 300". There are two circles, how can I revert them in my case?

Comment: I am using this path
<path id="textOnPath" fill="none" stroke="none" d="M 0 0 M -80 0 C -80 44.18277998646347 -44.18277998646347 80 0 80 C 44.18277998646347 80 80 44.18277998646347 80 0 C 80 -44.18277998646347 44.18277998646347 -80 0 -80 C -44.18277998646347 -80 -80 -44.18277998646348 -80 -9.797174393178826e-15" />

Comment: Still not sure what you need. Try this `d="M-80,0C-80,-44.18277998646348 -44.18277998646347,-80 0,-80C44.18277998646347,-80 80,-44.18277998646347 80,0C80,44.18277998646347 44.18277998646347,80 0,80C-44.18277998646347,80 -80,44.18277998646347 -80,0"` and let me know how it goes.

Comment: This is the issue I am facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76910089/fabric-js-handle-object-text-along-with-its-path-when-converting-to-svg